help with consumer grade routing
Trying to understand why I cannot reach other LAN devices on a ISP modem.
I have one ISP modem at 192.168.1.1. Already triple checked there is no option for client isolation or the likes.
then on one port I have a device 192.168.1.101 (it should receive connections from all interfaces on port 22. I tested moving it to a proper router using same dhcp ips)
I plugged another device on another port of the ISP modem and got 102.168.1.2
it's a linux device with NetworkManager handling dhcp.
It get's the following address and route:
$ ip a
2: enp3s0f4u1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b6:c3:97:fe:2e:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0f4u1
       valid_lft 258516sec preferred_lft 258516sec
    inet6 fe80::b4c3:97ff:fefe:2efb/64 scope link proto kernel_ll 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

 $ ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0f4u1 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.2 metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp3s0f4u1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 100 

But it cannot reach that other device. The trace is weird as it does not look like it even reaches the isp modem/router. but maybe i'm just clueless to the output here:
 $ tracepath -n 192.168.1.101
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.1.2                                         3030.125ms !H
     Resume: pmtu 1500

 $ tracepath -n4  192.168.1.1
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.1.1                                           1.089ms reached
 1:  192.168.1.1                                           0.857ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 1 back 1 


router have an option to setup port forwards, and if i set them up, I can connect and ping from outside to 192.168.1.101 fine.
It is a Sagemcom Fast 5657 device and there's no firewall or routing settings on the UI.

Sorry, home networking, consumer-grade hardware and host configurations/issues are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. You might want to try on [su].
